# json request gives ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i am trying to create user with a current login  user using 'Devise'. when i submit it gives error

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

Controller:

```
class AccountHoldersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def create
     @account_holder = AccountHolder.new(account_holder_params)
     respond_with(@new_doctor)
  end
end
```

view is in json.jbuilder;

Form

```
<%= form_for @doctor,format: :json, remote: true, html:{id:'add-doctor-form', class:'smart-form'} do |f| %>
```

Comment: What is the complete error? Are you sure you don't want to be serving .js?

Comment: @JustinM i solved this problem before your answer! Actually request for create Accountholder was going to AccountHolder::RegistrationsController not to simple AccountHolderController. I just added `respond_to :html, :json` in AccountHolder::RegistrationsController.